# How would I iterate through array and display input boxes based on values?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, npm, dropdown

I am new to react and I created I have a json like this:

```
const parent: [{name:will, kids['child1', 'child2']}
              {name: 'kia' kids['child1']}
              {name: 'jim', kids['child1', 'child2']}]
```

I am having trouble accessing the values with this json. I am trying to create a list with all the name values in of array so I can put it in a dropdown but I keep getting 'undefined' when i try to print the list in my console.log

Also when I click the name I want to create input boxes based of the length of the kids list of the name selected. So for instance if I click 'will' in the dropdown, two input boxes will form with 'child1' and 'child2' being in both input boxes. but if i click "kia", one input box will form that already has "child 1" in it. Any ideas? I have having a lot of trouble accessing the values.

this is my attempt so far:

```
import Dropdown from 'react-dropdown';


 parent: [{name:will, kids['child1', 'child2']}
              {name: 'kia' kids['child1']}
              {name: 'jim', kids['child1, 'child2']}]


 
class AppEX extends React.Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      parentnamelist: []
      parentname: null
      

    }
  }
  
 render() {
namelist: []
this.state.parent.map((e, key) => {
       namelist.push({value:e.name,label:e.name})
  })
        return (

<select name="select" onChange={this.namelist}>
  {num.map(function(n) { 
      return (<option value={n} selected={this.state.selected === n}>{n}</option>);
  })}
</select>
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are various problems here.

1. The `parent` list was not well formatted, is should look like this:

```js
const parent = [
  { name: "will", kids: ["child1", "child2"] },
  { name: "kia", kids: ["child1"] },
  { name: "jim", kids: ["child1", "child2"] }
]
```

2. You are using `map` in your `render` method to push parent names into a new list called `namelist` but you have to use `forEach`. `map` transforms a list while `forEach` does something to each member.

```js
const namelist = [];
this.state.parent.forEach(e => {
  namelist.push({ value: e.name, label: e.name });
});
```

3. Now `render return`:
   The `onChange` handler must be a function, since you want to track the selected parent, I guess you want to save it to your state:

```js
handleParentChoice = e => {
  e.persist();
  this.setState({
    parentname: e.target.value
  });
};
```

Then

```js
return (
  <div>
    <select name="select" onChange={this.handleParentChoice}>
      {namelist.map(n => (
        <option key={n.value} value={n.value}>{n.label}</option>
      ))}
    </select>
    <br />
    {this.state.parentname && // Shows below stuff only if parentname is not null
      this.state.parent
        .find(p => p.name === this.state.parentname) // Find the parent based on the saved name, then map the kids into input tags
        .kids.map(k => <input key={k} type="text" />)}
  </div>
);
```

Also, when you map something, every child should have a `key` prop.

[See the code working here](https://codesandbox.io/s/old-meadow-xsxj1?file=/src/aaa.js)

Comment: ohhhh i think i understand what i was doing wrong! thank you for the comments too!...is there any way to actually have the value inside of the input boxes? like when i click on will it will say "child1" in the one input box?

Comment: @JTHDR sure, just put the `value` prop on the `input` tag: `<input key={k} type="text" value={k} />`

Comment: ohhhhh ok! and i understand that i can access what is in the boxes with this.state...but i have one last question .., if the boxes change based on the len of childs...how do i still access the boxes with this.state lets say at the end if wanted to see both input values in a console.log?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get it.. The info about the selected kids is inside your state through `parentname`, what actually do you want to log, user input? kids name?

Comment: so what I mean is when i click 'jim' for instance. and now there is 3 input boxes. how do access each input box with this.state? i ask because lets say if in the console log I wanted to print a statement with the value of all 3 input boxes. would i access them with this.state? but how since I render them based on the len?

Comment: if you want to print the children just call `console.log(this.state.parent.find(p => p.name === this.state.parentname).kids)`. If you want to print some updated user input you should make those inputs controlled. See [Controlled Components](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components)

Comment: I tried using the contorlled components examples in the only thing that I'm not understanding is how to access each input afterwards. so when i click will and have a child 1 input box and a child 2 input box. if I changed inputbox 1 to ana and input box 2 to jimmy. how would i have a <h1> for instance that says "Will kids are Jimmy ana"? ... if that makes sense. thank you for your help once again!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219004/discussion-between-leverglowh-and-jthdr).